# Is there any way to hide the video controls from Notification Center on iOS 11.0?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In my app, I play a video from a `WebView` and I don't want to allow the users to stop the video, so I don't show any video control. But the controls still appear in `NSNotification` and in Control Center. Is there any way to hide them?

Comment: Why you do not use AVPlayerViewController? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller 

You can set property `showsPlaybackControls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView core functions are handled by the OS, so i think its not possible but you should implement the video/audio handling natively using these classes:

- **[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter) (currenlty playing items)**
- **[MPRemoteCommandCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter) (observe different events, play/pause/next.. )**